# Why does my learning curves shows spikes or fluctuations?

Tags: python, deep-learning, resnet, loss

My learning curves are giving fluctuations for a 3 class classification problem. I am training using Resnet 50 with
class 1 of 899 images
class 2 of 899 images
class 3 of 690 images.
My model gave a
train accuracy of 99.5%
validation accuracy 93%
test accuracy of 88%
with Epochs = 300, Batch size 32 and learning rate 0.1.
i tried tuning my parameters to epochs 50, 100, 200, 300, batch size 16,32, and learning rate 0.1,0.01,0.001,0.0001, still the spikes are present. Is the problem with my model or dataset? How can i actually know that my model is actually learning?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

'Spikes' are to be expected when training any model - especially with smaller batch sizes.

To understand why this could be so, assume the batch_size is 1 and in each epoch we start gradient descent with a random data-point and pick following data-points randomly as well.

This data-point helps us (the optimizer) find the direction to move in to find the closest minima. Now we move on to the next data-point, which again points towards the nearest minima. Throughout this epoch, we use the directions from each of our datapoints to find the minima and will give every datapoint equal weightage.

Thus, the order of the datapoints in which we go through to find the minima will have a drastic effect on what minima we get to.

Often times, with smaller batch_sizes, we might get stuck at local minimas (this gives us a huge loss) and sometimes we hit the jackpot with a more optimum minima (which will give us smaller loss).

This is one of the possible reasons you're getting good loss in some epochs and poor loss in others.

To answer your question about is your model actually learning anything, you should look at the smoothened loss graph. If the loss (or your metric) is improving over time then it means that your model is surely learning. If, however, the loss is fluctuating between two values, your model is not learning - as in the weights are not improving through backpropogation. This could be due to the fact that your dataset is just noise, your gradients are not being backpropogated, or other reasons which you can find [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352036/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-learn).

From your graph, although there is no mention of batch_size, the loss seems to be reducing wrt epochs. That means your model is learning.

If you want to smoothen the curve or get rid of the spikes, one of the thins you should try is training your model with a bigger batch_size, provided your VRAM can fit it.

Comment: The batch size i used is 32. I tried increasing it to 64 and 128, but there was no improvement. And the loss is very good for training but why only for validation the loss fluctuates? So as per @angryweasel 's comment the model is learning during training and not generalizing to my validation set. How else can i avoid these spikes that arise at the end/start of the epochs?